# Load report failed in Windows server 2003

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have an asp.net application,in which crystal reports is used.When i click on show button i get an error stating "Load report Failed".Application works fine in my local system.i also tried using report.close() and report.Dispose() but no luck.have also set permissions but still same problem.Can any one help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a valid Crystal Reports license on the server in which you are having problems?

Even with the free version that comes with Visual Studio, there is a license key that needs to be present on the machine in order to allow Crystal Reports to run. Here are a few solutions I've been through in the past:

1. Do a bare bones install of Visual Studio on the target server. Have it install C# and Crystal Reports and be done with it. The main issue is that Visual Studio will get the license key setup. I think technically you have to start a new project and drag a Crystal Report object onto the project to initiate the key install, but this could have changed over time.
2. Setup a merge module within your project to insert the Crystal Reports key. There is documentation on this on the Crystal Reports site. Sometimes this becomes a tricky process.
3. Install a full fledged copy of Crystal Reports on the target server. This assumes you have an a license of it available.

Unfortunately, none of these are really quick and easy solutions, but all of them have worked in the past. You just need to choose which will be the lesser of all evils for your shop. 8^D

Answer (score 1):

Check a couple of the basics:

1. Is the report in the directory that
   your application is expecting?  You mention that
   you've set the permissions fine, but
   double check that it actually IS
   looking in the right spot to begin
   with.  Maybe even print out the
   location it's looking for the report
   somewhere so that you can be sure.
2. Make sure that all of the tables,
   views and any other objects that the
   report uses are in place on the
   server, and that they match the same
   format.