# How to solve "Load Report Failed" in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I have one remote server (ex: 192.168.8.8) and one local server. I can run the crystal report which is on my local server without any issue.

But When I try to run on my remote server, it throws **Load Report Failed** error.

Here is my code:

**CrystalReport.cs**

```
protected void CrystalReportViewer1_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportDocument _rdStudents = new ReportDocument();
        string reportPath = Server.MapPath("~" + Request.QueryString["filename"].ToString());
        //string reportPath = Request.QueryString["filename"].ToString();
        _rdStudents.Load(reportPath);
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = _rdStudents;
    }
```

**CrystalReport.aspx**

```
<%@ Register Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" Namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" TagPrefix="CR" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" Height="962px" ToolbarImagesFolderUrl="" ToolPanelWidth="200px" Width="1344px"  HasRefreshButton="True" ToolPanelView="ParameterPanel" OnInit="CrystalReportViewer1_Init" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My report location is **//192.168.8.8/c$/inetpub/wwwroot/CrystalReportFiles/Test/Report1.rpt**

I check with this [crystal-reports-load-report-failed-error-running-report-on-the-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6879919/crystal-reports-load-report-failed-error-running-report-on-the-server) link.

I will not run the report directly using **Report FileName** attribute.

I tried with both category

```
string reportPath = Server.MapPath("~" + Request.QueryString["filename"].ToString());  //filename = /CrystalReportFiles/Test/Report1.rpt

string reportPath = Request.QueryString["filename"].ToString();  //filename=//192.168.8.8/c$/inetpub/wwwroot/CrystalReportFiles/Test/Report1.rpt
```

**I gave access to c:\Windows\Temp** to full control access for (IIS_IUSRS, USERS, Everyone)

I installed **CRforVS_13_0_20**

**Update**

> 1. I have CrystalReport.aspx file on my remote server also and my local server also
> 2. By passing parameter of file path(`//192.168.8.8/c$/inetpub/wwwroot/CrystalReportFiles/Test/Report1.rpt`) to `CrystalReport.aspx` (local server). I can run report
> 3. But I cannot run from `CrystalReport.aspx` which is on **RemoteServer(192.168.8.8)**, by passing the same path

Comment: yes, because your user does not have network access , you need a network user , IIS_users is local user.

Comment: @Ajay2707 What you mean network access for my user?. Even When I try to run directly from the Remote machine. it was not loading

Comment: do you mean you are not able to run crystal report with that path?

Comment: @Ajay2707 I can run the report from my local machine with the same path using CrystalReport.aspx file which is in my local server. But I cannot run the report using CrystalReport.aspx file which is on Remote server

Comment: forgot aspx, I mean to say open your remote rpt file in your local pc crystal report app. Are you able to open it and I think sure it will ask credentials.