# How to load Crystal report on Remote machine and not in Local Server?

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I want to run crystal report on Remote Server, instead of running in the local server.

For example, I have 2 servers called Server1 and Server2, Server1 as the local server whereas server2 is Remote connection.

> 1. I have my crystal report file on Remote server(Server2) on this below Location
>
> **//192.168.8.8/c$/inetpub/wwwroot/CrystalReportFiles/Test/Report1.rpt**
>
> 2. User will login and work on Server1
> 3. I have `CrystalReport.aspx` file Server1, which will load the file from the above location using below code

```
protected void CrystalReportViewer1_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReportDocument _rdReport = new ReportDocument();
    string reportPath = Server.MapPath("~" + Request.QueryString["filename"].ToString());
    
    _rdReport.Load(reportPath);
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = _rdReport;
}
```

So, When User run the report, will it load on the remote server? or on my local server?

Comment: I think this is not pretty much related to Crystal Reports. I understand that code runs on server side. If server1 hosts the application and "filename" is not a full path, then it will look for the file in server1. In this scenario, if you want to load the RPT from server2, you need a "reportPath" that server1 can access.

Comment: Is it duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52799635/how-to-solve-load-report-failed-in-asp-net)?